# Understanding Bessarabia for genealogy?

Tags: 20th-century, bessarabia

My grandparents, Albert Miller (Müller), born 1901, and Maria Staubert, born 1905, grew up in nearby villages in Beassarabia, perhaps Leipzig and another.

They met and and  married in 1925 (I believe in Leipzig). They made 2 attempts to immigrate to  Canada. The first however was stopped by the Navy when they learned my grandfather was a trained blacksmith. They were taken off the boat and sent back for him to work in the Navy. Their second attempt was successful.

My grandfather, pregnant grandmother and their one daughter, Tilly, departed from the Black Sea en route to Halifax, Nova Scotia, where they arrived May 13, 1927. They then took a train to Hannah, Alberta Canada where they had 7 children in total, 3 of whom are still living.

My grandmother, Maria was born to Nicolas and Katerina Staubert. Maria however, may have been known by the last name Keen. When her mother became sick and died, she was taken away from her father and her brother, and sent to live with the Keen family. It was apparently considered unsuitable for her father to raise her and shame was put upon them.  I believe she may have had step siblings within the Keen family however, from my understanding, never felt truly accepted. She never actually knew her brother or that she even had one. She only assumed she had one as she remembered seeing a family photo at one point where she was a baby and there was a young boy of about 2 or 3.

My grandfather Albert had a brother Reinhold Müller.

This is all I know about their history before they arrived in Canada.

I would like to know where Leipzig would be considered now? Moldova, Romania, Ukraine?

Comment: Hi Gigigogo, welcome. You have several questions buried in here. It would be best if you could ask them one question at a time. It's not really possible for people to tell you if you have cousins without doing extensive research, but someone experienced with genealogy in this part of the world may be able to give some tips. It would be best if you could ask your question about the location of Leipzig in another question.

Comment: Oh oops, thank you...obvious newbie.  Do you know if there is a specific place to throw out names and see if anyone responds re genealogy?

Comment: Likewise welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the 2-minute [Tour] that is designed to introduce all users to the protocols of its focussed Q&A format, which are quite different from those of bulletin boards, discussion forums and most other Q&A sites. On this site the only place "to throw out names and see if anyone responds re genealogy" is the [Roots Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6003/roots) but to talk there you will need to accrue 20 points of reputation by asking and answering questions, or suggesting edits to the posts of others that get approved.

Comment: I'll edit your question to try and reduce its scope to something that is more focussed, and that makes the question remain suitable for the one answer so far.  Please don't be offended by me editing your question.  Others editing your questions and answers to make them more focussed is one of the main things that makes this site different and much more successful in answering the difficult questions.

Comment: As a suggestion, I think your next question should be focussed on trying to find a marriage record for Albert and Maria, but that will need to be asked as a new question.  Feel free to cut/paste some paragraphs from this one.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that enables you to open it up for editing.

Answer (score 3):

Leipzig was located in Bessarabia and belonged to the Russian Empire until 1917. Afterwards it belonged to Romania until it was occupied by the Soviet Union in 1940 (place name: Серпневое/Serpnewoje). Today it belongs to Ukraine (named Серпневе). Wikipedia article (in German) on this place: 
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serpnewe

FamilySearch [has church records (lutheran 1824–1900) and other resources on this place](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/results?count=20&placeId=137490&query=%2Bplace%3A%22Russia%2C%20Bessarabia%2C%20Akkerman%2C%20Le%C4%ADpt%EF%B8%A0s%EF%B8%A1ig%22&subjectsOpen=490015-50,1092629-50,731128-50).

(I tried to answer one direct question from your text.)

Comment: Wow thank you! So now I understand why I have had confusion with my grandmother being Russian or Romanian or German or, or, or...thank you. I also know they were Luthern.